# Como extrair informações de um documento HTML com Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Estive estudando o exemplo do Jsoup para extração de dados e extrai um exemplo deste link [Jsoup](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/)

Porém tentei manipular o exemplo para extrair os dados de uma Div ao invés de um atributo Meta e não consegui.

Quero carregar os posts que as pessoas publicarem em um determinado blog e carrega-los na pagina do App.

Alguém pode me ajudar a modificar este código para pegar os dados da DIV.

```
package com.androidbegin.jsouptutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // URL Address
    String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the Buttons in activity_main.xml
        Button titlebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.titlebutton);
        Button descbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.descbutton);
        Button logobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logobutton);

        // Capture button click
        titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Title AsyncTask
                new Title().execute();
            }
        });

        // Capture button click
        descbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Description AsyncTask
                new Description().execute();
            }
        });

        // Capture button click
        logobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Logo AsyncTask
                new Logo().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    // Title AsyncTask
    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title
                title = document.title();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            txttitle.setText(title);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // Description AsyncTask
    private class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String desc;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Using Elements to get the Meta data
                Elements description = document
                        .select("meta[name=description]");
                // Locate the content attribute
                desc = description.attr("content");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set description into TextView
            TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desctxt);
            txtdesc.setText(desc);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // Logo AsyncTask
    private class Logo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data
                Elements img = document.select("a[class=brand brand-image] img[src]");
                // Locate the src attribute
                String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
                // Download image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set downloaded image into ImageView
            ImageView logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

A estrutura do site onde quero extrair os dados esta assim:

```
<div class="postWrapper" id="post162">

   <div class="postTitle">
      <h2> Titulo do post </h2>

      <div class="fb-custom-share" data-url="http://url..."></div>

      <div class="date"> 26 de janeiro de 2015 </div>
   </div>
   <div class="postContent">
      Conteudo
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta pegar todos os elementos com classe `postWrapper` que é onde o conteúdo do seu interesse está, para isso há o método `getElementsByClass`. Em seguida, basta iterar os elementos encontrados (que é um `Elements`) e acessar seu filhos. Visto que todos possuem classes, você pode usar o mesmo método mencionado acima para pegá-los.

A única diferença vai ser para pegar o link daquele atributo `data-*` `fb-custom-share`. Onde você vai precisar pegar o elemento pela classe e em seguida o atributo.

```
element.getElementsByClass("fb-custom-share").attr("data-url");
```

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("postWrapper");

for(Element element : elements){
   String title = element.select(".postTitle > h2").text();
   String share = element.getElementsByClass("fb-custom-share").attr("data-url");
   String date = element.getElementsByClass("date").text();
   String content = element.getElementsByClass("postContent").text();

   // salva em um ArrayList<ArrayList> ou um Map...
}
```

Segue um código de testes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Estrutura do HTML postado na pergunta.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.append("<div class=\"postWrapper\" id=\"post162\">")
                .append("<div class=\"postTitle\">")
                    .append("<h2>Título A</h2>")
                    .append("<div class=\"fb-custom-share\" data-url=\"linkA\"></div>")
                    .append("<div class=\"date\"> 26 de janeiro de 2015 </div>")
                .append("</div>")
                .append("<div class=\"postContent\">")
                    .append("Conteúdo A")
                .append("</div>")
            .append("</div>");

        // Faz o parse da String e tenta transformá-la em um documento.
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html.toString());

        Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("postWrapper");

        for(Element element : elements){
            System.out.println("Título: " + element.select(".postTitle > h2").text() +
                               "Link de compartilhamento: " + element.getElementsByClass("fb-custom-share").attr("data-url") +
                               "Data: " + element.getElementsByClass("date").text() +
                               "Conteúdo: " + element.getElementsByClass("postContent").text());
        }
    }
}
```

#### `output:`

> **Título:** Título A
>  **Link de compartilhamento:** linkA
>  **Data:** 26 de
>   janeiro de 2015
>  **Conteúdo:** Conteúdo A